# How to get the URI of a ROS node in Python?

Tags: uri, ros, rospy

I'm trying to find machines that publish a certain type of message. Therefore I'm inspecting the list of rosnodes `rosnode.rosnode_listnodes()` and would like to **get the IP address of the corresponding machines running a specific node**.

There is a method `rosnode.lookup_uri(...)`, but I have no idea how to use it. I also looked into the `rospy`, `rosgraph`, `names` and `network` modules - so far without success. Among other information,`rosnode.rosnode_info(node_name)` prints the URI. But it might be a rather expensive method and, unfortunately, it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [huanxiner](http://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) answered on [ROS answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/247262/how-to-get-the-uri-of-a-ros-node-in-python/?answer=247266#post-id-247266), you can use `lookupNode` from the `rosgraph` module as follows:

```py
import rosgraph
master = rosgraph.Master("")
print master.lookupNode("node_name")
```

The result is something like this:

```
http://192.168.123.1:45678/
```